# ListView Columns Header - after last header there is a white gap

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, templates

It's hard to explain with words. 
I did a style and template for ListView similar to this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/listview-styles-and-templates
I turned out like this: 
[image]

As you can see, in the header, there is a weird white gap after the last column. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Normally you can set the width in WPF like `width = "*"` and it would automatically fill the empty gap. However, as far as I know, it is not possible to do in `ListView`. You can either have a fixed width or have it on auto. If I were you I would switch to `DataGrid`.

If you really want to stick to `ListView` I would suggest to have a custom `IValueConverter`. You can `Bind` the `Width` of `GridViewColumn` to the `ActualWidth` of the `ListView`.

```
public class StarWidthConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            ListView listview = value as ListView;
            double width = listview.Width;
            GridView gv = listview.View as GridView;
            for (int i = 0; i < gv.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                if (!Double.IsNaN(gv.Columns[i].Width))
                    width -= gv.Columns[i].Width;
            }
            return width -5;// this is to take care of margin/padding
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe your ListView is inside a Grid so default value for HorizontalAlignment  will be Stretch , ListView will auto generate a blank column to fill all availible space,to avoid that you can put your ListView inside a StackPanel then set Orientation to "Horizontal" or explicity set HorizontalAlignment value for ListView .Something like this

```
<ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
```